# How to configure IP Address inside Cubic

Tags: custom-distributions

so, i've got this project from my teacher to make custom operating system for online exam using cubic in ubuntu, he asked me to configure the ip address inside the cubic, i've spend many times searching how to configure the ip and couldn't find it, so i just want to ask, is it possible to config the ip address inside the cubic? and if it possible did you know how to do it. thank you.